# Sending image over websockets (from python backend to javascript frontend)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, websocket, base64

I'm trying to send a frame from a video feed in open cv-python over websockets to react js frontend.

I can encode and send it fine, but when I try to decode it I get an error that reads that the string wasn't properly encoded.

backend code

```
    #open url to view info
    stream_url = urlopen(url)
    
    #read information from url, convert array into bytarray 
    stream_feed = stream_url.read()
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(stream_feed), dtype="uint8")
    str_frame = str(b64encode(frame))
    payload = json.dumps({
              'image': str_frame
               })
    await remoteSocket.send(payload)
```

frontend code

```
const image = decodeURIComponent(atob(orgImg))
const img = new Image()
img.src = image
img.alt = 'frame'
```

the string to contain a b before before the single quotes, I thought that might be it so I trimmed it off and no luck. I've also tried it without decodeURICompoenet.
And I've tried it by adding data:image/jpeg;base64 to the start.

Comment: Tell me where did you get the frame in the string str_frame = str(b64encode(frame))?

Comment: I actually figured this out already, I just modified the beginning of the string on my client side